# Are there tricks to calcualte the complete elliptic integral the third kind fast?

Tags: matlab, elliptic-integrals

I use matlab to work on some algorithm. I need to solve all three kinds complete elliptic integrals. I noticed that for the first and second kind, matlab funlction `ellipke` is very fast. However for `ellipticPi` function, it is very slow (I work with column vectors in 10k scale). I am wondering if there are any tricks that I can use to calculate the results faster, beside numerical methods.

Thanks.

Comment: https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S037704271300201X?token=02390F0FB80C88180BDDCCA0F62445F040F6FD22F32E1B3AFECEB4D5E521330E1E1817CCB4F80523069F291081EC6379&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20221030041505 could be interesting to look at

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236135659_Fast_Computation_of_a_General_Complete_Elliptic_Integral_of_Third_Kind_by_Half_and_Double_Argument_Transformations/link/5a34f4d4aca27247eddd1f73/download is more recent (by the same author)

Comment: Hi Claude, the paper is very nicely written. Thanks for the help. If you can write in an anwser section. I will accept it.

Comment: It is not worth to do it. But, for other users, you could add an answer to your own question to tell the key points and features you got from the papers. Cheers :-)